# Retreving all objects where a datetime field resolves to a date in another timezone

Tags: django, timezone, models

Let's say that I have a model like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
    start_time = DateTimeField()
```

Now, all of the events are stored in the database in UTC. Now, on the views side I have a class like this:

```
class EventListDay(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
    year, month, day = int(self.kwargs['year']), int(self.kwargs['month']), int(self.kwargs['day'])
    target_day = datetime.datetime(year,month,day) #naive date type
    target_day = timezone.make_aware(target_day, timezone.get_current_timezone()) #aware date time
    return Event.confirmed_objects.get_events_for_day(target_day).order_by("start_time")
```

Now, when this view is called I get a queryset with all events that fall on that day. The only issue is that the events that are returned are from that day *in UTC*. So, for example, I am in the "America/Chicago" timezone and any events that take place after 7pm appear on the next days list.

What I am asking is how to I make the query in such a way that the events returned fall on that day in the *current* timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have since solved my issue. What I did was to create TWO datetimes from the supplied kwargs. One was the beginning of the day, one the end. I then made both of the datetime objects aware and attached the current tz to them. I then used .filter( start_time
__range=(starttime, endtime)